# Batteries with normal time to recharging

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I self study statistic and I came across one problem that I need help. I try to use CLT in this problem, but in first part deviation makes
me a problem. In second part I really have no idea how to start problem.

One company has developed a new cell phone battery. Battery's lifetime on a single charge is normally distributed with(population)
standard derivation of $10$ minutes. Suppose the manufacturing department runs a quality control test by randomly selecting a $n$
batteries.

Assume that $n = 8$. Calculate the probability that sample standard deviation is between $9$ and $12$ minutes.

Since manufacturing department doesn't know population mean, they want to estimate average lifetime based on a simple random sample.
How large should be their sample that margin of error of their estimation is $2$ minutes at the level of confidence of $98\%$.

Comment: Please edit some progress toward solution into your Question. I'll give a couple of clues.

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

As  you should know, in a gaussian model, $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi_{(n-1)}^2$

Thus as you are looking for the probability that $9<S<12$ you can check the probability

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[\frac{7\times 9^2}{100}<\chi_{(7)}^2<\frac{7\times 12^2}{100}\Bigg]=\mathbb{P}[5.67<\chi_{(7)}^2<10.08]\approx 39.47\%$$

using a calculator or tables. With tables the result will be more inaccurate, depending on the precision of your tables.

---

> Why 2.236. How you get that number and how you get $\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$?

- 2.236 is a typo. @Bruce would write 2.326 that is the standard gaussian quantile at 99%

In fact your exercise is asking you a 98% confidence result so you have to discard the two queues, 1% left and 1% right. If you read the tables  you see that at $P(Z\leq z)=0.99$ they give you $z\approx 2.326$

- $\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$ is the standard deviation of the sample mean; as you should know,

$$\overline{X}_n \sim N(\mu;\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$$

Going back to the exercise,

**Question 2.**  The confidence interval of your unknown mean is

$$\overline{X}_n-2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\mu\leq\overline{X}_n+2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$$

the size of the interval is evidently

$$\overline{X}_n+2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}-[\overline{X}_n-2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}])=2\times2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$$

this means that you have an estimated error of $\pm$ half of the interval, say

$$2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$$

If you need that your error shoul be equal to 2 minutes you have only to solve in $n$ the equation

$$2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}=2$$

that gives you $n=135.30$

so you have to approx $n=136$ because $n=135$ is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) Sample variance $S^2$ has $\frac{7S^2}{10^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 7).$
You want $9^2 \le S^2 \le 12^2.$
Use printed tables of chi-squared distributions or software.

(2) 98% CI is of the form $\bar X \pm 2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}},$ where the margin of error must be
$2 = 2.326\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}.$ Solve for $n.$

Comment: Why 2.236. How you get that number and how you get $\frac{10}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: In your Q, you say you want a 98% confidence interval, You want to cut 1% from each tail of the standard normal dist'n. If $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ then $P{-2.326 \le Z \le 2.326} = 0.98.$ @Tommik has kindly noted my typo, which I'm going to fix. And I think he has explained $10/\sqrt{n}.$